# Fetching JSON and iterating through the values in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native, and I'm trying to simply iterate through a sample json file but am receiving the error **undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state.results.map')**

I have set the state initially to be an object, so not sure why i am receiving this error.

**Here is the JS**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

var REQUEST_URL = 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json';

class WPReact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {results: []};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          results : { responseData }
        });
      })
      .done();
  }
  render() {
    return this.renderJSON();
  }
  renderJSON() {
    contents = this.state.results.map((item) => {
      <View key={item.movies.title} style={ styles.container }>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          {item.movies.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
     });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {contents}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

// App registration and rendering
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => WPReact);
```

---

## EDIT

So i have edited the renderJSON() to and also removed the braces of responseData as you said, as it was already an object:

```
renderJSON() {

    console.log(this.state.results.description);
    contents = this.state.results.movies.map((item) => {
      <View key={item.title} style={ styles.container }>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          {item.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
     });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {contents}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I added a console log to see if i can output some of the data, and i can see the description. The sample JSON i am using is (demo from react):

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977"},
    { "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985"},
    { "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999"},
    { "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010"},
    { "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014"}
  ]
}
```

I can log the description and title. But I am still receiving: `ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.results.movies.map')`

And if I try logging `console.log(this.state.results.movies[0].title)` I am receiving `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.results.movies[0]')`

```
fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        this.setState({
          results : responseData
        });
      })
      .done();
  }
```

console.log(responseData) shows:

```
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS: { title: 'The Basics - Networking',
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:   description: 'Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!',
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:   movies: 
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:    [ { title: 'Star Wars', releaseYear: '1977' },
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:      { title: 'Back to the Future', releaseYear: '1985' },
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:      { title: 'The Matrix', releaseYear: '1999' },
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:      { title: 'Inception', releaseYear: '2010' },
03-29 13:49:53.028  3062  4143 I ReactNativeJS:      { title: 'Interstellar', releaseYear: '2014' } ] }
```

console.log(this.state.results.movies);

```
03-29 14:18:05.483  3062  4726 I ReactNativeJS: undefined
03-29 14:18:05.510  3062  4726 I ReactNativeJS: [ { title: 'Star Wars', releaseYear: '1977' },
03-29 14:18:05.510  3062  4726 I ReactNativeJS:   { title: 'Back to the Future', releaseYear: '1985' },
03-29 14:18:05.510  3062  4726 I ReactNativeJS:   { title: 'The Matrix', releaseYear: '1999' },
03-29 14:18:05.510  3062  4726 I ReactNativeJS:   { title: 'Inception', releaseYear: '2010' },
03-29 14:18:05.510  3062  4726 I ReactNativeJS:   { title: 'Interstellar', releaseYear: '2014' } ]
```

Comment: what happens when you `console.log(this.state.results.movies)`?

Comment: I've modified my original post to show you, not sure why there is an undefined there?

Comment: This occurs even after you use `JSON.parse` as I suggested in my amended answer?

Comment: Ahah you are logging the results before setting them into state!  Log them before you call `this.renderJSON` in your `render` method

Comment: @Pineda putting `console.log(this.state.results.movies)` in the render method outputs the same as above what i posted, still shows undefined.

Comment: You are sure you are only making that one console.log call in render now?

Comment: @Pineda - it appears to working now alongside the other answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What fixed it specifically?

Comment: @Pineda i believe it must have been not declaring the states properly in the constructor.

Comment: The way you had it initially was fine.  Maybe something went out of sync with all the changes.  Glad you found a solution.  If you found my answer helpful, an up-vote would be greatly appreciated  (when you gain enough rep of course :D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see a couple of things you need to change.

Firstly, you need to bind fetchData method when you are using ES6 doing this `this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);` in the constructor (look for other ways to do this).

Secondly, `map` should be applied to `this.state.results.movies` due this is the array (following your post). `this.state.results` is not an array, is an object containing an array.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

var REQUEST_URL = 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json';

class WPReact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      //Lets initialize results with the same struct we expect to receive from the api
      results: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        movies: []
      }
    };
    //Using ES6 we need to bind methods to access 'this'
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          results: responseData
        });
      })
      .done();
  }

  render() {
    //this.state.results.movies is the array you have to iterate
    contents = this.state.results.movies.map((item) => {
      //We need to return the corresponding mapping for each item too.
      return (
          <View key={item.title} style={ styles.container }>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              {item.title}
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
     });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {contents}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

// App registration and rendering
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => WPReact);
```

Let me know if its works, I havent tested yet but I will soon.

Comment: The fetch is working without the bind. The issue is with the data that it is returning...

Comment: Take a look at my second point. I think he needs to iterate results.movies instead

Comment: That second point is now moot, given the EDIT to the original question as a result of suggesting this exact point an hour ago :)

Comment: Well, in the constructor, `results` is being initialized as an array. Why not trying to separate `results` in `movies` in one hand and rest of info in the other?

Comment: Depends on if the results returns one object or many.  In the current case it returns a singular object, there is a possibility it was intended to return an array.  This is something for the OP to clarify

Comment: The fetch doesn't have to be bound, nor does the call to renderJSON.  They are both within the scope of the ES6 class.

Comment: I am for now trying to output a list of movie titles basically, this is a small experiment as part of a bigger project later - but it's giving me a few problems.

Comment: I've created this playground for testing it: https://sketch.expo.io/Hk3IuVKne . I'm working on it to see what is going on

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca it appears to be working with what you posted. I just tried it, i had to remove the `return` in `return response.json()`, i was getting errors. I'm assuming my constructor was set up incorrectly and also discovered I didn't include `return` in `contents`

Comment: oh Great!!! I've edited my answer to remove `return` from `return response.json()`, It was a copy/paste mistake. And The problem was probably in the constructor. Could accept my answer if it worked? Thanks.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca thanks it helps me alot. can you help me here [Please-help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137961/how-to-show-filtered-json-data-from-two-different-key-values-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

React components using ES6 classes don't autobind `this` to non React methods. In your constructor, add:

`this.renderJSON = this.renderJSON.bind(this)`

Comment: If what you say is the case, wouldn't `this.fetch` also fail?

Answer (score 0):

`responseData` has to be an array for the `Array#map()` method to be available as a method on it.

You are setting `results` to an object containing the value of your `responseData`:

```
this.setState({ 
  results : { responseData } // Object literal notation albeit possibly incorrect depending on the value of responseData
});
```

Remove surrounding braces if you are sure `responseData` is an array:

```
this.setState({ 
  results :  JSON.parse(responseData);
  // You'll want to parse your JSON data here too :)
  // If responseData is an array, you'll be able to call .map on it
});

// this.state.results.movies.map should now work
// (given the structure of the expected JSON)
```

Comment: so i have removed the braces, and has got me a little further, but still receive the same map error.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the value returned in `responseData`? It could be that the value returned is not an array

Comment: So this looks like you receive a single object.  Are you expecting an array of these objects, or are you trying to map through the titles property?

Comment: I've amended my answer to include the parsing of the JSON data when setting the results property on state

Comment: when i add that, i get `JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"`

Comment: Ahah, so it's likely that the code does not need to be parsed.  It doesn't explain why your log for this.state.results.movies is undefined where are you calling this console log