# how to show filtered JSON data from two different key values in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

Here is my JSON data

```
{
  "profile": [
    {
      "proid": {
        "user": "kohinoor"
      },
      "image": "/media/profiles/DSCN3253.JPG",
      "shoptype": "Clothes",
      "city": "Ahemednagar"
    },
    {
      "proid": {
        "user": "shrawani"
      },
      "image": "/media/profiles/PicsArt_08-17-09.24.48_qA94ILU.jpg",
      "shoptype": "Cat Shop",
      "city": "Kopargaon"
    },
    {
      "proid": {
        "user": "rajpal"
      },
      "image": "/media/profiles/PicsArt_08-17-09.24.48_T3birjf.jpg",
      "shoptype": "Clothings",
      "city": "Sangamner"
    },
  ],
  "post": [
    {
      "id": 120,
      "content": "Old Mi Stocks or Sell !!!",
      "url": null,
      "shareproductdealer": "kohinoor",
      "shareproducttype": "Xiaomi Mi",
      "shareproductid": "68",
      "username": "kohinoor",
      "updated": "2017-09-08T10:49:11Z",
      "timestamp": "2017-09-08T10:49:11Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 119,
      "content": "Hello... Miahe...",
      "url": null,
      "shareproductdealer": null,
      "shareproducttype": null,
      "shareproductid": null,
      "username": "shrawani",
      "updated": "2017-09-08T10:38:14Z",
      "timestamp": "2017-09-08T10:38:14Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 115,
      "content": "hello jockey",
      "url": null,
      "shareproductdealer": "rajpal",
      "shareproducttype": "jockey",
      "shareproductid": "65",
      "username": "rajpal",
      "updated": "2017-08-16T11:22:32Z",
      "timestamp": "2017-08-16T11:22:32Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this data there are two key values `profile` and `post`.

I want to show data from `profile` with respective data from `post` by checking `user` from profile and `username` from post. Means i want add data from profile with the respective data of post.

Here is my react native code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: {
        isLoading: true,
        profile: [],
          user:'',
            proid: '',
            image: '',
            shoptype: '',
            city: '',
        post: [],
          username: '',
            content: '',
            url: '',
            timestamp: '',
            id: '',
      }
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }
```

render method

```
render() {
    contents = this.state.results.post.map((item) => {
      return (
          <View key={item.id}>
            <Text>
              {item.id}
            </Text>
            <Text>
              {item.username}
            </Text>
            <Text>
              {item.timestamp}
            </Text>
            <Text>
              {item.content}
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
     });
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {contents}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

This only prints all data from post. Not integrating the respective data as i need.

So how can i achieve that filteration of respective data by checking those two values? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. Iterate over profiles with [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and for each item create a new object, which is consisted from the profile itself and on the posts filter the appropriate posts using [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). And then show this data in your React code.

**Javascript example.**

```js
const data = {
  "profile": [
    {
      "proid": {
        "user": "kohinoor"
      },
      "image": "/media/profiles/DSCN3253.JPG",
      "shoptype": "Clothes",
      "city": "Ahemednagar"
    },
    {
      "proid": {
        "user": "shrawani"
      },
      "image": "/media/profiles/PicsArt_08-17-09.24.48_qA94ILU.jpg",
      "shoptype": "Cat Shop",
      "city": "Kopargaon"
    },
    {
      "proid": {
        "user": "rajpal"
      },
      "image": "/media/profiles/PicsArt_08-17-09.24.48_T3birjf.jpg",
      "shoptype": "Clothings",
      "city": "Sangamner"
    },
  ],
  "post": [
    {
      "id": 120,
      "content": "Old Mi Stocks or Sell !!!",
      "url": null,
      "shareproductdealer": "kohinoor",
      "shareproducttype": "Xiaomi Mi",
      "shareproductid": "68",
      "username": "kohinoor",
      "updated": "2017-09-08T10:49:11Z",
      "timestamp": "2017-09-08T10:49:11Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 119,
      "content": "Hello... Miahe...",
      "url": null,
      "shareproductdealer": null,
      "shareproducttype": null,
      "shareproductid": null,
      "username": "shrawani",
      "updated": "2017-09-08T10:38:14Z",
      "timestamp": "2017-09-08T10:38:14Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 115,
      "content": "hello jockey",
      "url": null,
      "shareproductdealer": "rajpal",
      "shareproducttype": "jockey",
      "shareproductid": "65",
      "username": "rajpal",
      "updated": "2017-08-16T11:22:32Z",
      "timestamp": "2017-08-16T11:22:32Z"
    }
  ]
};

const profiles = data.profile;
const posts = data.post;

const profilePosts = profiles.map(item => ({
  profile: item,
  post: posts.filter(post => post.username === item.proid.user)
}));

console.log(profilePosts);
```

Comment: Sir, actually i am fetching my data from here [json data](http://myjson.com/tffbl), so how to get that data in const variable.

Comment: @mayureshpatil don't take a look at my variables. Just see what logic I wrote in the `profiles.map(...)` function and use it in your code with your variables.

Comment: hello @Suren Srapyan according to above logic posts are arranged according to profiles but those both are in different key-values i.e `profile` and `post` which are under `profilePosts` and it gives me problem to show. As i am using above render method as mentioned. i want both under one key.

Comment: Should i post new as a question or no problem?

Comment: also tried `finalresult: profile.concat(post)` but showing error that profile is not defined...